# history of backpropagation

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, artificial-intelligence, cybernetics

Has anybody read or have access to

Alex Andrew
    Significance Feedback in Neural Nets
Report of Biological Computer Laboratory, University of Illinois, Urbana, IL
    GM-10718-03
TR No 5
September 1965
pages 1--12

and can confirm the contribution this made to backprop?

Now, the basic routine is done by economists since the late 19th century for inferring value to factors of factors of  ... production, with the chain rule, but for neural networks, this is cited by cybernetics oriented persons as the very first application. Is it?
Margaret Boden cites Paul Werbos as first but that I have read (it was republished in his book) but Werbos's dissertation came a decade after Andrew's report.

I have seen this cited as the first modern backpropagation in cybernetics paper, and not surprisingly it is from the place where McCulloch, Ashby, et al worked. But I can't access it to confirm.
Alexander passed away recently so can't contact him either.
Anybody have this thing, or read it, or have it scanned?
Archive.org has some of the other reports (for example, on asynchronous computers) but not this one ...

UPDATE: Interlibrary loan cannot get ahold of a copy of the first edition. They gave up on all requests! Does anybody have this paper, or the reprint of it from the 1990s?

Comment: Presumably you've tried the University of Illinois, Urbana's library?

Comment: Yes, have a loan request there, no response yet from UoI to my university library...

Comment: I found a scan of it online at this link: http://bclarchive.net/browse/ (there doesn't seem to be a way to link directly to the document, but it's at the top of the page if you sort by fiche). I would post this as an answer but it would be link-only since I can't comment on the document's contributions (I'm not very familiar with neural nets).